# Why is django-compressor modifying CSS files instead of simply concatenating them?

Tags: css, django, django-compressor

I have recently deployed a Django-based site. I was looking for ways to speed up page loads, so I decided to give [django-compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor) a try.

My home page includes quite a few CSS and JS files, so django-compressor seemed like the perfect tool for the job. I modified the template for the home page to take advantage of django-compressor's CSS concatenation capabilities:

```
{% compress css %}
  <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/file1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/file2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endcompress %}
```

Unfortunately, the problem is that django-compressor is modifying the files. `file1.css` contains a large number of declarations and `file2.css` contains some new declarations and overrides some of the declarations in `file1.css`. Unfortunately some of the declarations in `file2.css` are missing (part of the file is there - but part of it isn't).

This still happens even when I set:

```
COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = []
```

...in `settings.py`. The files are concatenated but some of `file2.css`'s declarations are missing. Is there some setting I don't know about that is causing the file to be modified or declarations to be dropped? Nothing like this happens with the JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I forgot to run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

...and therefore the missing attributes were due to the fact that the static directory contained an older copy of the CSS file.